# Is it possible to exit a function in Haskell with it's current return type?

Tags: haskell, error-handling

Is it possible to have a function that returns Int to close the program on an error? For example, and exit with a chosen value?

Here is my code:

```
example :: String -> Int
example s = do
let j = read  s
case j of
    0 -> j
    _ -> exitWith (exitFailure: 84)
```

I just want to stop the program on an error in a function that is not IO, and I can't find a way but using the "error" function, which doesn't return any value.

Comment: `exitWith` has type `exitWith :: ExitCode -> IO a`, so it can not return an `Int`. But it is very *odd* to do an exit anyway, since a non-IO function has no specific evaluation order. It thus can mean that the program will evaluate it at a completely different timestamp than when you intend to.

Comment: Often a non-total function is emulated with a `Maybe ...` as return type.

Comment: You could use `error`, but that would be "*ugly*" for the same reasons as listed above.

Comment: Does this mean putting Maybe Int could work ?

Comment: you do not *exit* the program with such `Maybe`, the point is that you use it to "*encode*" the non-totalness of the function. So then you can inspect that in the `IO` monad (for example `main`, and let `main` perform an `exitWith`).

Comment: Yes but is there a way to return a value using error, so that when I type `echo $?` it displays a chosen value ?

Comment: With your function, no. With an IO action that *uses* your function, yes.

Comment: If there's an error with `read` (it's a partial function), your `case` expression won't see it. Your program just stops then and there. You need to catch the exception, or use a total function in the first place.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest sort-of-clean option could be to throw an exception (those can also be thrown in pure code), catch it in `main` (we need to be inside `IO` to catch them), and there use `exitWith`. Still, it's rare to use exceptions in Haskell, so this is not really idiomatic (indeed, I don't even remember how this is concretely done in code; I'd need to google that). Still, why would a pure function need to abort the program?

Comment: @chi yes, I think this is exactly the sort of situation where an exception is the right approach.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Could be. To be honest, I think we could even have a pure `errorWith :: ExitCode -> a`, since it would be not really worse than `error` (IMO). But we can't implement that without unsafe primitives, so exceptions seem to be the "best" alternative which is still kosher.

Comment: The _trace_ function from Debug.Trace manages to write tracing info on stderr while in pure code. Similarly, would it be possible to write a C function that would call exit(), and then call that C function from pure Haskell code using the [FFI](https://wiki.haskell.org/Foreign_Function_Interface) (Foreign Function Interface) using a clause like `foreign import ccall "myExit" ... ` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option as the comments says is Maybe:

```
example :: String -> Maybe Int
example s = do
let j = read s
case j of
    0 -> Just j
    _ -> Nothing
```

and then, whenever you use it you can pattern match over the Maybe value. That is not the same as "exit the program". But it is a way to handle a failure.

Other way is with `Either`

```
type ErrorMsg = String 

example :: String -> Either ErrorMsg Int
example s = do
let j = read s
case j of
    0 -> Right j
    _ -> Left "exitFailure: 84"
```

Comment: I tried to do something like this, but now the result is considered as a `Maybe Int`, which means I can't pass it to a function that takes a simple `Int` as parameter.

Comment: @Osa “which means I can't pass it to a function that takes a simple Int as parameter” – well, that's somewhat by design. The function _doesn't_ return a simple `Int` as the result in the error case, so... — Then again, we do need to recognise that Haskell isn't a total language, _can_ crash, and it could be debated whether giving a particular exit code should be considered an illegal side-effect any more than `error`. I think chi's suggestion of an exception makes sense here.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I'd like to do it but as you can see/guess, I'm quite a beginner in Haskell, and I still don't understand how to throw/catch exceptions

Comment: @leftaroundabout but isn't there a way to do something like : if the function returned Nothing, then exitWith(etc), else send the result as an Int ? Since it's either an Int or Nothing ?

Comment: @Osa Certainly: in your `IO`-based caller, you may run `do { v <- case example "foo" of { Nothing -> exitWith (ExitFailure 84); Just v -> pure v }; ... }` and in the `...`, you will have `v :: Int`. Or, you may change `example` to do `IO` directly, as in `example :: String -> IO Int; example s = case read s of 0 -> pure 0; _ -> exitWith (ExitFailure 84)` and then in your `IO`-based caller you may `do { v <- example "foo"; ... }` and again you will have `v :: Int` in the `...`.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the issue that if `read` is what raises the exception, it doesn't matter if you change the return type from `Int` to `Maybe Int`, because `j` never gets set, let alone examined.

Comment: @chepner I wasn't clear about something, my example with read was just an example, I actually don't use read, I just wanted to be able to interrupt my program in a given situation, which I was able to do now

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative, exploiting exceptions.

First, we declare a custom exception type, containing our `ExitCode`

```
import Control.Exception
import System.Exit

data TerminationException = TE ExitCode
   deriving Show

instance Exception TerminationException where
```

Then, we can use it in pure code, throwing an exception as needed.

```
example :: String -> Int
example s = let
   j = read s
   in case j of
      0 -> j
      _ -> throw (TE (ExitFailure 84))
```

Note in passing that the above `read` will crash the program if the input string does not parse to a number. I'm including that only to be as close as possible to the original code, but it would be better to use `readMaybe` or `reads`, instead.

We can then define a little exception handler.

```
withExit :: IO a -> IO a
withExit action = action `catch` (\(TE code) -> exitWith code)
```

Finally, we need to wrap the `main` with our handler, as follows.

```
main :: IO ()
main = withExit $ do
   putStrLn "hello 1"
   print (example "0")  -- passes
   putStrLn "hello 2"
   print (example "1")  -- ** --
   putStrLn "hello 3"
```

The above `main` triggers the exception at the `**`-marked line. There, nothing is `print`ed and the program is exited with return code `84`, as specified in `example`.